# Populate Django SearchVectorField with bulk_create()

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to use the [performance `SearchVector`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvectorfield), using `SearchVectorField` in model but it seems it is not possible to populate `SearchVectorField` on insert for some reason.

All documentation I read only gives me either `.annotate(search=SearchVector('...'))` or `.update(search_vector=SearchVector('...'))` and I don't want to use either.

Using `annotate` approach would be slower.
Using "performance" `update` approach I need to first create the record and do a second query to populate the `SearchVectorField`.

Because I'm using `.bulk_create()` it would make sense to insert `SearchVector` results on the fly since I have all the values already and not create another query to update `SearchVectorField` but for some reason it is not possible.

Is it really not possible or am I missing something?